# Rails, get record with has_and_belongs_to_many having more than one value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

given these models

```
modelOne
    has_and_belongs_to_many :model_twos

modelTwo
    has_and_belongs_to_many :model_ones

    field_one: string
```

how would I use active record to get all the modelOnes that had associated modelTwos where `field_one` equalled `"value_1"` and `"value_2"`

something like `ModelOne.joins(:model_twos).where(model_twos:{field_one: "value_1" AND "value_2"})`

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed somewhat tricky, if you want to use ActiveRecord only (i.e. without falling back to Arel).

I'm not 100% certain it will work or even produce desirable SQL but I'd try something like this:

```
class ModelOne < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_model_two_value, -> (val) { joins(:model_twos).where(model_twos: { field_one: val }) }
end

ModelOne.with_model_two_value('value_1').merge(ModelOne.with_model_two_value('value_2'))
```

Comment: It worked, the sql ended up looking like `SELECT "model_ones".* FROM "model_ones" INNER JOIN "model_ones_model_twos" ON "model_ones_model_twos"."model_one_id" = "model_ones"."id" INNER JOIN "model_twos" ON "model_twos"."id" = "model_ones_model_twos"."model_two_id" WHERE "model_twos"."field_one" = $1  [["value_1", "value_2"]]`

Comment: never mind, it didn't work, I had a typo in my negative tests

Comment: I feared as much. I guess you'll probably need to add some Arel or SQL after all.